# Unity3D: Instantiating a prefab by its class

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

In my unity3D project I have a manager script that should take care of initializing a game level, instantiating and placing all relevant prefabs. However, I can't find a way to instantiate a prefab by its class - it turns out that "instantiate" really means something more like "clone" in Unity3D. So as a workaround, I had to make my manager script a `MonoBehaviour`, attach it to an empty object and assign my prefabs to it from the inspector since it is the only way I have found to make it work at all. This looks kind of awkward. Is there any way to actually instantiate a prefab, without cloning it from a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load prefabs at runtime. Just have a look at the script reference which comes with examples:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

Here is an article that should clarify how it works:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html

Comment: I would just add that after you load a resource so need to instantiate it, this is because you're actually loading prefabs, but you need GameObjects at runtime, which you get by instantiating the prefab